# ASP.NET page formatting does not works

Tags: asp.net

I have deployed an ASP.NET website on IIS 7. I was able to access my site using the URL `http://**local host**/sitename.aspx` and all the formatting of my pages is looking good.

But when I access the same page by using the URL `http://**servername**/sitename.aspx` from another system or on the same server where I have been deployed, the page formatting is not working properly.

What would be the best solution for this? Thanks

Comment: What does "the page formatting is not working properly" mean? Please give more details, code might be necessary.

Comment: Refer developer console see if their is some unresolved error for e.g. error related to path where css file is saved.

Answer (score 1):

First a fall to check your Js/Css file path where you have not mention static file path with localhost name.

For more detail go to browser and browse your url and press F+12 so development tool will be open and check there for broken url.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. The problem happens only on IE and rest of the browsers displays properly at all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are worrying about formatting soo much. I mean formatting should not affect you much unless you use `<pre>` in your html.

There are ways to modify the HTTP Response Using Filters. Can you please makesure none of these filters present in your application for release mode.

Generally i use HTTP compression feature of IIS to compress my content, but in browser it looks correct to me.